# Why does OISST trend for this year appear to be increasingly diverging from the mean since early March?

Tags: climate-change, climate-models, wildfire

With recent news about hottest global daily temps on record, I came across climatereanalyzer.org from the University of Maine.

I ended up looking at their [data for daily sea surface temperature](https://climatereanalyzer.org/clim/sst_daily) and noticed that all other years substantially overlap with at least several other years in their trend.

The same is true for 2023 until early March, when the OISST data increases rapidly so that by mid-March it no longer overlaps with any other years. In addition, the divergence seems to be continually increasing since then.

[image: OISST chart showing temperature divergence in 2023]

Is there something wrong with the OISST data or does this represent an actual change in SST?

I know next to nothing about this topic but I do note that this time period appears to correspond very closely with the Canadian wildfires. Is it possible atmospheric conditions from the fires have skewed the global record?

Comment: There is a strong El Niño going on, so at least part of it is real.

Comment: A recent article at science.org suggests recent rapid warming could also be due to less oceanic cloud cover resulting from stricter pollution standards for shipping. https://www.science.org/content/article/changing-clouds-unforeseen-test-geoengineering-fueling-record-ocean-warmth

Comment: For future reference, you might want to include a snapshot of the graph in question, because your link points to whatever the current measurements are.  Someone clicking on your link in some months or years time will see a very different graph.

Comment: I suspect more of it is return to neutral after 3 consecutive la Nina's that masked recent warming than el Nino. Most of the effects of the current el Nino won't be felt until early next year, so expect the records to keep being broken.